# How can I do an explicit declaration of std::str::Matches<'a, P> in Rust?

Tags: rust, match

Suppose, I want to do an explicit declaration of `Matches<'a, P>` type.

What actual types can I pass for `'a` rather than using `_`?

```
 use std::str::Matches;

fn main() {
    let my_string = "Hello. I have a string and a substring.";
    let pat = "ing";

    let matches: Matches<'_, &'static str> = my_string.matches(pat);

    println!("{}", matches.count());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you create the object. For your case you are using [matches](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.matches) function to create `Matches` .
Let's check the definition of `matches`:

```rust
pub fn matches<'a, P>(&'a self, pat: P) -> Matches<'a, P>
where
    P: Pattern<'a>,
```

When you call `my_string.matches(pat);` then `'a` becomes the lifetime of `my_string`. (`my_string` is `&'static str` then `'a` will be`'static`)

It would be **arbitrary lifetime** when `my_string` typed as `String`.

In your case you cannot explicitly declare lifetime, it will be fetched from my_string,
but consider a function like this:

```rust
use std::str::Matches;

fn count_ings<'a>(source: &'a str) -> usize {
    let matches: Matches<&'a str> = source.matches("ing"); //explicitly declared

    matches.count()
}

fn main() {
    let my_string = "Hello. I have a string and a substring.".to_string();

    println!("'ing' count: {}", count_ings(&my_string));
}
```

IMHO this brings minor protection to a `matches` var, but if you want to use it, just use it. Also you can even opt out lifetime declaration, there is no need to add a wild card thanks to lifetime elision.

```rust
let matches: Matches<_> = source.matches("ing"); //replace with the line above.
```

Answer (score 1):

For [`Matches<'a, P>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Matches.html), you have `where P: Pattern<'a>`. So in your case, it would be `'static`:

```
let matches: Matches<'static, &'static str> = my_string.matches(pat);
```

Comment: What would be the type if I use nonstatic `&str`?

Comment: For `&'foo str`, it should be Matches<'foo, &'foo str>

Comment: but, in my comment there is no `'foo`...

Comment: For a non-static `&str`, if there is no lifetime, it means that your lifetime has been ellided; in this case either you name your lifetime earlier in the type declaration, either you use `Matches<'_, &str>`, because the lifetime has not been named

Comment: @yolenoyer unfortunately  for `&'foo str`,  type still can be `Matches<'foo, &'static str>` since the latter one is the type of the pattern not the target.